# Which numbers identify inputs and outputs in circuit breaker

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

[image: Numbering of circuit breaker]

I have always though that the numbering on the circuit breaker is in as such that the input wire (supply line) is 1 (3,5,7) and the output wire is 2 (4,6,8). However today I discovered that in my panel the input wire is 2, and the output wire is 1. Is this correct? And does it matter?

Comment: Does the breaker have explicit LINE/LOAD type markings on it?

Comment: No I thought that the numbering serves this purpose

Comment: Except in the special cases of DC breakers with permanent magnets, and some breakers with electronics, it does not matter and will usually specify so several pages into the datasheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can go either way. often the feed to a panel goes "backwards" through the main breaker (compared to the other breakers).